# fwrite fails to write value 10 (0x0A)

Tags: c, fwrite

I was experimenting on creating BMP files from scratch, when I found a weird bug I could not explain. I isolated the bug in this minimalist program:

```
int main()
{
    FILE* ptr=NULL;
    int success=0,pos=0;
    ptr=fopen("test.bin","w");
    if (ptr==NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    char c[3]={10,11,10};
    success=fwrite(c,1,3,ptr);
    pos=ftell(ptr);
    printf("success=%d, pos=%d\n",success,pos);
    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
success=3, pos=5
```

with hex dump of the `test.bin` file being:

```
0D 0A 0B 0D 0A
```

In short, whatever value you put instead of `11` (0x0B), `fwrite` will write it correctly. But for some reason, when `fwrite` comes across a `10` (0x0A) - and precisely this value - it writes `0D 0A` instead, that is, 2 bytes, although I clearly specified 1 byte per write in the `fwrite` arguments. Thus the 3 bytes written, as can be seen in the `success` variable, and the mysterious `5` in the `ftell` result.

Could someone please tell me what the heck is going on here...and why 10, why not 97 or 28??

Thank you very much for your help!

EDIT: oh wait, I think I have an idea...isn't this linked to \n being 0A on Unix, and 0D 0A on windows, and some inner feature of the compiler converting one to the other? how can I force it to write exactly the bytes I want?

Comment: The bug is in your code. ;) Your file was opened in text mode so CRLF translation is being done. Try: `fopen("test.bin","wb");`.

Comment: Yes, I just realized, right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your file was opened in text mode so CRLF translation is being done. Try:

```
fopen("test.bin","wb");
```

Comment: Yep. I can only close the question in 10 minutes!

Answer (score 3):

You must be working on the Windows machine.  In Windows, EOL is CR-LF whereas in Unix, it is a single character.  Your system is replacing 0A with 0D0A.